# Microsoft Access exception reports/comparing results

Tags: ms-access

I have a general question.  I will be seeing my manager in 2 days and she said she wanted to test my knowledge in microsoft access vba.  She hinted that i will be to ' generate exception reports and comparing results'.  Could you guys tell me what that is?  I suspect that we can get those 'reports and compare results' by using them 'select arguments'. 
 I apologize for sounding ignorant but i have never used access before.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: after doing some research online does 'exception reports' mean there is are missing values in some of the column that 'isnull' or empty?

Comment: The closest thing in VBA to exceptions are runtime errors - see [Error Handling in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ErrorHandling.htm). But I have no idea if that's what is meant.

Comment: he added that it will be : 30 min on VBA coding in Access using a simple form and 30 min in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It's a trick hint - you can't *generate exception reports* in Access except if you create a system for collecting exceptions - whatever that will be - and she would have to define that before you could create those.

However, as you *have never used Access before*, your knowledge in Access VBA will be nil, and you are hosed anyway. So skip the test and ask for a budget for a couple of books and an intro course.